# Setting bar plot with the histc option in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set my bar options with one command line.  I am using the "histc" option and it plots as I expected except for the FaceColor setting. MATLAB returns no error and when checking the `a` value in the workspace, the FaceColor remains with the default settings.

```
x = 1:10;
y = rand(10, 1);
figure
ax = axes;
a = bar( x, y,'histc', 'FaceColor', [0.7, 0.5, 0.1], 'Parent', ax );
```

I am able to set the FaceColor using the additional command line below but I don't understand why I have to use the `set` function to do so. (without the "histc" option, it works without adding any command line)

```
set(a , 'FaceColor', [0.7,0.5,0.1])
```

Is my code wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the other two *style* options for `bar`: `grouped` and `stacked`, `histc` (and `hist`) cannot be used together with *Name-Value* pairs (as answered [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98152-why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-hist-and-histc-with-the-parameter-value-syntax-in-matlab-7-9-r2009b)).

So if you would like to use `bar(... ,'histc')`, you will have to add additional options later:

```
set(a, 'FaceColor', [0.7,0.5,0.1]);
% ... or for newer versions
a.FaceColor = [0.7,0.5,0.1];
```

Another workaround suggested [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91944-how-can-i-combine-the-options-histc-and-stack-in-a-bar-plot-in-matlab-7-4-r2007a) from the time when  `bar` together with  `histc` was a undocumented feature, but it seem a bit trickier then the "post-set-option"